# Make a UILabel Block Touch Events To UIViews Behind It

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UILabel on a UIView.

[image]

The UIView has a double-tap to zoom in feature. However, if the user double taps on the text, I want a text editor to come up and I don't want the image to zoom. Right now if they double tap the text, the editor comes up and it zooms in.

Do you know how I can make the UILabel swallow touch events?

Objc and Swift answers welcome!

Comment: the double tap is done with Gestures? if so get the location of the UILabel and make sure that if the Tap is hitting that UILabel box location just ignore that Zoom call. and allow the rest to work the same.

Comment: Thats bad design though IMO. The UIView shouldnt need to know or care about whether a touch occured on an object on top of it. It should just respond. The UILabel should be able to stop the command moving forward and keep its reponsbility contained

Comment: I agree with you. the object on top should be intercepting the Gesture and the Object behind should not be even noticing that action unless being touched directly. So either is a problem with their design of how Gestures work or is intended and we should work around it.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable user interaction for it and add a dummy gesture recognizer. You can easily do that from storyboard or code **(Swift 3)**:

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.gestureRecognizers = [UIGestureRecognizer()]
```

Comment: This alone is not enough, though. The gesture recognizer needs to intercept the touches. So it needs to be a `UITapGestureRecognizer` where `numberOfTapsRequired = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UITextView for it

Answer (score -2):

You just need to set user interaction enabled.

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Then it sounds like you've got a touch listener attached to a superview of both.

Comment: Yes the view (green image) has a listener as does the text. This is because the image is listening for double taps to zoom, but I want double taps on the UILabel to block the massage to the image. But I dont think there is a listener on the 'root' UIView